# Flutter Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to create a flutter app which uses Textinput. I created TextInput as class named "Textinput" and function "renderTextInput" to have more compotibility I set values in TextInput by using class TextInputData with get`s and set`s. Code doesn't mark me errors.

```
class Textinput {
  void renderTextInput(TextInputData textInputData) {
    Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: textInputData.getText()),
        keyboardType: textInputData.getType(),
        style: textInputData.getStyle(),
      ),
      width: 400.0,
    );
  }
}
```

```
class TextInputData {
  String? _text;
  TextInputType? _type;
  TextStyle? _style;
  TextInputData(text, type, style) {
    _text = text;
    _style = style;
    _type = type;
  }
  String? getText() {
    return _text;
  }

  void setText(text) {
    _text = text;
  }

  TextInputType? getType() {
    return _type;
  }

  void setType(type) {
    _type = type;
  }

  TextStyle? getStyle() {
    return _style;
  }

  void setStyle(style) {
    _style = style;
  }
}
```

usage in code

```
textInput.renderTextInput(TextInputData(
                "почта", TextInputType.emailAddress, _sizeTextBlack))
```

and how I call it in main

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(title: 'Navigation Basics', home: AuthorizationScreen()));
}
```

If you know how to solve it please tell me. I would really appreciate.

Comment: where are you using `textInput.renderTextInput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code structure, I think you need to return the widget

```dart
class Textinput {
  Widget renderTextInput(TextInputData textInputData) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: textInputData.getText()),
        keyboardType: textInputData.getType(),
        style: textInputData.getStyle(),
      ),
      width: 400.0,
    );
  }
}
```